# How do I create (d) elements arrays out of another array of (n > d) elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

For example, we have the array:

`let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]  //(n = 9)`

Now i want to create maximum amount of arrays of d = 5:

Array1: `arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]`

Array2: `arr2 = [2,3,4,5,6]`

Array3: `arr3 = [3,4,5,6,7]`

Array4: `arr4 = [4,5,6,7,8]`

Array5: `arr5 = [5,6,7,8,9]`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more solution using a reducer:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
const size = 5

const result = arr.reduce((acc, _, i) => {
  if (i <= arr.length - size) acc.push(arr.slice(i, i + size))
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Caveat: if `size > arr.length`, `result` will be an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Simple `for` loop and [array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) should work in this case:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
let d = 5;

let result = [];

for(let i = 0; i <= (arr.length - d); i++){
   result.push(arr.slice(i, d+i));
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you want to keep your "sub-arrays" in the same order as your initial array?:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

console.log(generateSubArrs(arr, 5));

function generateSubArrs(arr, d){
  const outputArrs = [];
  const n = arr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i <= (n - d); i++){
    const tempArr = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < d; j++){
      tempArr.push(arr[i + j]);
    }
    outputArrs.push(tempArr);
  }
  return outputArrs;
}
```

Output:

```js
[
  [    1,    2,    3,    4,    5  ],
  [    2,    3,    4,    5,    6  ],
  [    3,    4,    5,    6,    7  ],
  [    4,    5,    6,    7,    8  ],
  [    5,    6,    7,    8,    9  ]
]
```